# Android use rotation matrix from SensoryManager

Tags: android, android-sensors

Android has the function:
`SensorManager.getRotationMatrix`

Which you can use to get a rotation matrix expressed as a float[]. I can do the maths to multiply some other vector (e.g. coming out of the accelerometer). Obviously it's better to re-use existing functionality if possible though - is there a standard way in Android to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take the accelerometer provided by the device's sensor ?

If the device has accelerometer sensor and gyroscope sensor you better take the values from the Sensor.

```
SensorEvent event;
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

   if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        timestampAccSys = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timestampAcc = event.timestamp;
        valueAccX = event.values[0];
        valueAccY = event.values[1];
        valueAccZ = event.values[2];
        newValueAcc = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I want consistently oriented accelerometer values.